# Upper bound of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

I am looking for an upper bound of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$. Alternatively, is the sequence $\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ bounded?

I am trying to use a Strong law of Large Numbers by Feller and need to show this condition.

Comment: Maybe specify a bit about what you are looking for would help. Say, $k$ is a straightforward upper bound for the sum...

Comment: Note: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\leq\int_{0}^{n}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{n}.$$

Comment: Not in terms of $O(1)$ but the bound is of form $\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=O(\sqrt{k})$.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed.

Comment: I meant $n{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via a comparison series and integral:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = 
\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{k}}
\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}
= \int_{0}^{n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}
= 2\sqrt{n}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

Lets use a powerful [Riemann Zeta Function Identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{k}} & =
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k^{\color{red}{1/2}}} =
{n^{1 - \color{red}{1/2}} \over 1 - \color{red}{1/2}} + \zeta\pars{\color{red}{1 \over 2}} +
\color{red}{1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over
x^{\color{red}{1 /2} +1}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
2\root{n} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2} +
{1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x 
\end{align}
However,
$$
{1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x <
{1 \over 2}\int_{n}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{3/2}} = {1 \over \root{n}}
$$

---

$$ \\
\mbox{Then,}\quad
\bbx{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{k}} <
2\root{n} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2} + {1 \over \root{n}}}\\
$$
Note that $\ds{\zeta\pars{1/2} < 0}$.

---

$$
\mbox{Also,}\quad
\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}{1 \over \root{k}} + {1 \over \root{n}} <
2\root{n} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2} + {1 \over \root{n}}
$$
$$ \\
\mbox{which leads to}\quad
\bbx{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{k}} <
2\root{n + 1} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2}}\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ is a $p$-series with $p\le 1$, hence it diverges.

Alternatively,
$$0<\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt 1}=\frac1{\sqrt n}\le1.$$

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I know it diverges. I needed an upper bound on the rate at which it diverges, and learned that an upper bound on the rate is $\sqrt{n}$. I am a bit confused by your proof of the upper bound of the sequence. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For $k\le x<k+1$,

$$\frac1{\sqrt k}<\frac1{\sqrt{x-1}}.$$

Integrate from $1$ to $n+1$.