# Deceptively simple asymptotic

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I am trying to show that:
$$\sum_{k=2}^n \sqrt{\frac{n^2}{k-1}} = O(n^{1.5})$$

Obviously, we want to show that

$$n\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k-1}} = O(n^{1.5})$$
With Cauchy-Schwartz we can see that:

$$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k-1}} \leq \sqrt{n}\left(\sum_{k-1}\frac{1}{k} \right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{n}\left(\gamma + \log(n) + \frac{1}{2n} \right)^{1/2}$$

where $\gamma$ is the Bonferroni constant, and I just interpreted the second norm as a [truncated Harmonic series approximated by Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Approximation_using_the_Taylor_series_expansion).

Thus, overall we get
$$\sum_{k=2}^n \sqrt{\frac{n^2}{k-1}} \leq n \sqrt{n} \left(\gamma + \log(n) + \frac{1}{2n} \right)^{1/2}  = O(n^{1.5}\log(n))$$

Which is not exactly the result, but it might be just that the authors hid the logarithmic dependencies).

What do you think?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3745324/42969, where it is shown that $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k-1}} = O(n^{1/2})$.